# Script to trigger alert when new renko brick forms

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have this code for trigger alert when new opposite color renko brick create, but i need to modifired it to create alert when new renko brick create no matter what color it is. each time new brick created, i need a notification, please help me to modifed this scriot to my need.
Thanks in advance.

The Script i have this :

```
//@version=4
study("Candle Alert", overlay=true)
greencandle = close >= open
redcandle = close < open
colorchange = (greencandle and redcandle[1]) or (redcandle and greencandle[1])
alertcondition(colorchange, title="Candle color changed")
plotshape(colorchange)
```

I tried but didn't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` function triggers an alert with no conditions. Since the script executes on each bar end, you can trigger an alert on that moment. Add to your script:

```
alert("Bar closed")
```